# TypeError: e.fn.cycle is undefined - Jquery cycle 2

Tags: jquery-cycle2

Get this console error when trying to implement JQuery Cycle2:

TypeError: e.fn.cycle is undefined

```
<script type="text/javascript"  src="jQuery1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="margaretha/js/jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="margaretha/js/jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>
```

What could be wrong here?

Comment: If anon answered your question please select it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of your javascripts maybe? "jquery.cycle2.min.js" should be included before "jquery.cycle2.carousel.min.js".